# Laravel Application with Synology NAS

Tags: laravel, apache, synology

I have installed php composer in synology NAS device under usr/local/bin, As synology provide apache server application, I enabled it as well.

I have install laravel in below location

cd /var/www/html
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel test_laravel

But when i try to open this on URL its giving me 404 error, I have no idea how to start Apache server that go ahead and integrate with Synology web station?

Comment: how you config the Apache? /var/www/html/ is the host root? but you created the project as /var/www/html/test_laravel , so means no index file at /var/www/html/ , if you go to http://hostname/test_laravel , did you see the Laravel welcome screen?

Comment: Synology provide a Apache package so i install that apache 2.4. I did not configure apache separately. I am not getting Laravel welcome screen just getting 404 error. I am not sure how and where Synology configure Apache and how i can go ahead and install laravel over there.